# Set a public integer from an activity to an other activity

Tags: android, variables

IN my first activity I have this code (that is a onCLick event of a Button):

```
  public void uno(View v)
   {
    Partita p = new Partita();
    p.cont = 1;
    p.puntiCategoriaG1 = 20;
    p.puntiCategoriaPC = 15;

    Intent i = new Intent(this, Partita.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
  }
```

And in the second class/activity I set them:

```
public class Partita extends Activity {
   public int cont;
   public int puntiCategoriaG1;
   public int puntiCategoriaPC;
   @Override
   public void onCreate(....
```

But when I go to use them in the code the have the value 0. How can I solve?

Comment: You should learn about `Intent.putExtra`

Comment: this is just wrong way of doing things...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add a parameter into `Intent`

```
public void uno(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Partita.class);
    i.putExtra("cont", 1);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

And now in your second `Activity` you can retrieve it:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    int cont = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("cont", 0);
    Log.d("TAG", cont);
}
```

You have not to create an instance of `Partita` activity before launching.

```
Partita p = new Partita();
p.cont = 1;
p.puntiCategoriaG1 = 20;
p.puntiCategoriaPC = 15;
```

When you call `startActivity(i);` you don't start this created object. Android builds and shows the `Activity` itself. To pass some parameters into the second `Activity`, add them into `Intent` as I described above.

Comment: But i need to decide the value of the variable in the 1st activity and in the second only take it. In this way i set the value in the second activity @yital

Comment: No, you set the value in "public void uno(View v)" method in the first Activity: i.putExtra("cont", p.cont). At this point cont = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("cont ", 0); you read it. "0" here is the default value, if you didn't set any value to Intent with such key

Comment: i put i.putExtra("cont",cont); with cont =1 in the first activity and i put public int cont = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("cont",0); in the second activity.....but when i launch the app it closes when i click

Comment: did you add your second Activity into manifest?

Comment: i think no...ii need to insert?
--edit--- <activity android:name=".Partita" /> is this?

Comment: yes, right, in <application> block

Answer (score 0):

see when you start activity you just pass the .class I.e the object of Class.java associated with Partita.java. 
You should not create the object of Activity. You just start it and its the Android framework which takes care of creating the object and calling the lifecycle methods of an activity. 
You use Objecy of Intent.java to start an activity. 
For passing data from one activity to another I suggest you to study about putExtra method in Intent.java. Also study about as how to wrap data in Bundel and then how to pass it to object of Intent which is used to start new activity.

Answer (score 0):

Android Activities do not work like normal classes. ie: You do NOT specifically create the instance. You simply create an Intent with the intention to start a specific activity. The operating system takes care of initializing the instance of the new activity.

Passing data between activities is different than passing data within classes. Please check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-on-android) to see how it's done.